# Sum of <td> in dynamic Jquery

Tags: html, jquery

I have this table where I show in the td of white color is the consolidated information of the td of gray color.

Like this:

[image]

The yellow color fields "- Und" It should show the sum of the fields below.

The correct result would look something like this:

[image]

I have identified the tds by an id, but I can't get it to add up.

- tdgray = gray
- tdwhite = white

```js
var total = 0;
$(".tdgray").each(function() {
  total += parseInt($(this).text()) || 0;
});
$(".tdwhite").text(total);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<TABLE BORDER>
  <TR>
    <TD>price</TD>

  </TR>

  <TR>
    <TD id="tdwhite" class="tdwhite"></TD>
  </TR>
  <TR>
    <TD class="tdgray">421</TD>
  </TR>
  <TR>
    <TD class="tdgray">124</TD>
  </TR>
  <TR>
    <TD class="tdgray">982</TD>
  </TR>
  <TR>
    <TD id="tdwhite" class="tdwhite">Und</TD>
  </TR>
  <TR>
    <TD class="tdgray">200</TD>
  </TR>
  <TR>
    <TD class="tdgray">200</TD>
  </TR>
  <TR>
    <TD class="tdgray">200</TD>
  </TR>
  <TR>
    <TD class="tdgray">200</TD>
  </TR>
</TABLE>
```

If you see the result works but adds all the gray tds and does not go from record to record, I have a table with more than 300 white tds, can be a problem some solution?

[LOOK THE EXAMPLE HERE](https://jsfiddle.net/qp8yxfne/)

Comment: don't use `.html()` use `.text()`

Comment: I just edited the question with the change, but it seems to remain the same.

Comment: Can u see the example here ->https://jsfiddle.net/qp8yxfne/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your explanation of what you are needing is quite confusing.

I believe this is what you are looking for. It uses `nextUntil()` to loop through the rows that have a tdgray after each tdwhite and sums that group

```js
$(".tdwhite").text(function() {
  var total = 0;

  $(this).parent().nextUntil(':has(.tdwhite)').each(function() {
    total += parseInt($(this).find('.tdgray').text()) || 0;
  });

  return total

});
```

```css
.tdwhite{color:red}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<TABLE BORDER>
  <TR>
    <TD>price</TD>

  </TR>

  <TR>
    <TD id="tdwhite" class="tdwhite"></TD>
  </TR>
  <TR>
    <TD class="tdgray">421</TD>
  </TR>
  <TR>
    <TD class="tdgray">124</TD>
  </TR>
  <TR>
    <TD class="tdgray">982</TD>
  </TR>
  <TR>
    <TD class="tdwhite">Und</TD>
   
  </TR>
  <TR>
    <TD class="tdgray">200</TD>
    
    
  </TR>
  <TR>
    <TD class="tdgray">200</TD>
  </TR>
  <TR>
    <TD class="tdgray">200</TD>
  </TR>
  <TR>
    <TD class="tdgray">200</TD>
  </TR>
</TABLE>
```

Comment: Perfect! but, if I want to put exactly the same value but in an input that is inside that td? how would it be?

Comment: Which class has the inputs? Can you update your fiddle to refelect it?

Comment: Look ->https://jsfiddle.net/4wh2gqxv/3/

Answer (score 1):

Here is another (Vanilla JavaScript) solution:

```js
document.querySelectorAll(".tdwhite").forEach(el => {
  let p, total = 0;
  for (p = el.parentNode.nextElementSibling;
    (p && !p.querySelector('.tdwhite')); p = p.nextElementSibling)
    total += +p.querySelector('.tdgray').textContent || 0;
  el.textContent = total
});
```

```css
.tdwhite {
  color: red
}
```

```html
<TABLE BORDER>
  <TR>
    <TD>price</TD>

  </TR>

  <TR>
    <TD id="tdwhite" class="tdwhite">one</TD>
  </TR>
  <TR>
    <TD class="tdgray">421</TD>
  </TR>
  <TR>
    <TD class="tdgray">124</TD>
  </TR>
  <TR>
    <TD class="tdgray">982</TD>
  </TR>
  <TR>
    <TD class="tdwhite">Und</TD>

  </TR>
  <TR>
    <TD class="tdgray">200</TD>


  </TR>
  <TR>
    <TD class="tdgray">200</TD>
  </TR>
  <TR>
    <TD class="tdgray">200</TD>
  </TR>
  <TR>
    <TD class="tdgray">200</TD>
  </TR>
</TABLE>
```